# Does the for(i in array) update?

Tags: node.js, for-loop, filesystems

Ok, so I have this code

```
var cwd = __dirname;
var files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname);
for(var i in files){
    if(fs.lstatSync(files[i]).isDirectory(path.join(cwd, files[i]))){
        var cur = fs.readdirSync(path.join(cwd, files[i]));
        for(var j in cur){
            files.push(path.join(files[i], cur[j]));
        }
    }
}
console.log(files);
```

This code checks if the path of `files[i]` is a directory, and if it is, it gets the contents of that directory and stores it in the variable `cur`. It then parses `cur`, and adds its contents to `files`. But, I'm getting directories when it logs `files`. Is this because the `for` loop is only taking the content of `files` at the initiation of the loop? Is there a way I can make the loop update to the current content of `files`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for in` takes only index that exist before entering the loop.

You can use `while` instead.

```
var i=0
while (files[i]){
    if(fs.lstatSync(files[i]).isDirectory(path.join(cwd, files[i]))){
        var cur = fs.readdirSync(path.join(cwd, files[i]));
        for(var j in cur){
            files.push(path.join(files[i], cur[j]));
        }
    }
    i++
}
```